# flowplayer with splash image not woring with embed code

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, flowplayer

I have configured one flowplayer with RTMP streaming and embed code generation feature,
embed code generation used object based method,the main problem is, i can't add splash image in embed code, I have googled lot but get any solution. if any one know how add splash image on flowplayer embed code, please post your valuable suggestions with this thread.

```
<object data="http://adultseotraining.com/player/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.15.swf" height="400" id="undefined" name="undefined" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="730">
  <param name="movie" value="http://adultseotraining.com/player/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.15.swf"/>
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"/>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
  <param name="flashvars" value="config={"key":"#$4ce811ab676ba73755d","clip":{"autoPlay":false,"provider":"rtmp","connectionProvider":"secure","autoBuffering":true,"url":"mp4:test.mp4"},"plugins":{"rtmp":{"url":"http://adultseotraining.com/player/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.11.swf","netConnectionUrl":"rtmpe://142.4.13.20:1935/vod"},"secure":{"url":"http://adultseotraining.com/player/flowplayer.securestreaming-3.2.8.swf","token":"R%23Mk%25F5%256d@1E0%23wa"},"gatracker":{"url":"http://adultseotraining.com/player/flowplayer.analytics-3.2.8.swf","events":{"all":false,"resume":"Unpause","mute":false,"unmute":false},"debug":false,"accountId":"UA-37520370-1"},"controls":{"url":"http://adultseotraining.com/player/flowplayer.controls-3.2.14.swf","backgroundGradient":"none","sliderColor":"#FFFFFF","sliderBorder":"1.5px solid rgba(160,160,160,0.7)","volumeSliderColor":"#FFFFFF","volumeBorder":"1.5px solid rgba(160,160,160,0.7)","timeColor":"#ffffff","durationColor":"#FFFFFF","tooltipColor":"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)","tooltipTextColor":"#000000"}},"playlist":[{"autoPlay":false,"provider":"rtmp","connectionProvider":"secure","autoBuffering":true,"url":"mp4:test.mp4"}]}"/>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, and the workaround is to use playlist with the first item as the image file, and the second item as the video.
Basically just dump everything in your "clip" into the second playlist item.